# My Job Postings Are In Google For Jobs But Not Showing In GSC Job Postings Report

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-jobs

While the majority of the listings published on our website are present on Google For Jobs, only 19 listings are visible in the Job Postings section of Google Search Console. Additionally, in the Indexing > Pages section of Google Search Console, I can see that approximately 6300 listings from the sitemap are indexed, and the structured data within them is being properly read.

Previously, in the Google Search Console > Job Postings section, the total number of listings was visible, but currently, this value is significantly lower.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance from someone who has experience and knowledge regarding this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Here are some screenshots;

[image: Google For Jobs]

[image: GSC > Indexing > Pages]

[image: Indexed Job Posting]

[image: GSC > Job Postings]

[image: GSC > Job Postings With Impressions]